# Httpc Error Erlang

Tags: json, http, erlang, cowboy

I am starting development with Erlang and need to make a REST HTTP call to a server where I send a JSON and receive JSON confirmation.

Follows the code

```
Method = put,
URL = "http://api.teste.com:8080/v1/user_auth",
Header = [],
Type = "application/json",
Json = <<"{ \"data\" : { \"test-one\" : \"123\", \"test-two\" : \"return test 2\" } }">>,
HTTPOptions = [],
Options = [],

application:start(ssl),
application:start(inets),

httpc:request(Method, {URL, Header, Type, Json}, HTTPOptions, Options).\
```

When you run this code I am with the following error:

```
=ERROR REPORT==== 5-Dec-2015::14:21:01 ===
Error in process <0.161.0> on node 'middleware@127.0.0.1' with exit value:
{[{reason,undef},
  {mfa,{user_account_handler,handle_post,2}},
  {stacktrace,[{httpc,request,
                      [put,
                       {"http://api.teste.com:8080/v1/user_auth",[],
                        "application/json",
                        <<"{ \"data\" : { \"test-one\" : \"123\", \"test-two\" : \"return test 2\" } }">>},
                   [],[]],
                  []},
                {cowboy_rest,call,3,[{file,"src/cowboy_rest.erl"},{line,972}]},
                {cowboy_rest,process_content_type,3,
                            [{file,"src/cowboy_rest.erl"},{line,773}]},
                {cowboy_protocol,execute,4,
                                [{file,"src/cowboy_protocol.erl"},
                                 {line,442}]}]},
  {req,[{socket,#Port<0.479>},
        {transport,ranch_tcp},
        {connection,keepalive},
        {pid,<0.161.0>},
        {method,<<"POST">>},
        {version,'HTTP/1.1'},
        {peer,{{127,0,0,1},49895}},
        {host,<<"localhost">>},
        {host_info,undefined},
        {port,8080},
        {path,<<"/v1/create_user_account">>},
        {path_info,undefined},
        {qs,<<>>},
        {qs_vals,undefined},
         {bindings,[]},
        {headers,[{<<"host">>,<<"localhost:8080">>},
                  {<<"connection">>,<<"keep-alive">>},
                  {<<"content-length">>,<<"58">>},
                  {<<"cache-control">>,<<"no-cache">>},
                  {<<"origin">>,
                   <<"chrome-extension://fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop">>},
                  {<<"content-type">>,<<"application/json">>},
                  {<<"user-agent">>,
                   <<"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.73 Safari/537.36">>},
              {<<"postman-token">>,
               <<"2dc302f2-7c93-b9f9-2143-cff41bfeb45a">>},
              {<<"accept">>,<<"*/*">>},
              {<<"accept-encoding">>,<<"gzip, deflate">>},
              {<<"accept-language">>,
               <<"en-US,en;q=0.8,es;q=0.6,pt;q=0.4">>}]},
    {p_headers,[{<<"content-type">>,{<<"application">>,<<"json">>,[]}},
                {<<"if-modified-since">>,undefined},
                {<<"if-none-match">>,undefined},
                {<<"if-unmodified-since">>,undefined},
                {<<"if-match">>,undefined},
                {<<"accept">>,[{{<<"*">>,<<"*">>,[]},1000,[]}]},
                {<<"connection">>,[<<"keep-alive">>]}]},
    {cookies,undefined},
    {meta,[{media_type,{<<"application">>,<<"json">>,[]}},
           {charset,undefined}]},
    {body_state,waiting},
    {buffer,<<"{\n    \"username\":\"igor@gmail.com\"\n    , \"password\":\"123\"\n}">>},
    {multipart,undefined},
    {resp_compress,false},
    {resp_state,waiting},
    {resp_headers,[{<<"content-type">>,
                    [<<"application">>,<<"/">>,<<"json">>,<<>>]}]},
    {resp_body,<<>>},
    {onresponse,undefined}]},
  {state,undefined}],
 [{cowboy_rest,process_content_type,3,
               [{file,"src/cowboy_rest.erl"},{line,773}]},
  {cowboy_protocol,execute,4,[{file,"src/cowboy_protocol.erl"},{line,442}]}]}
```

Comment: There's more going on that you're saying, because that stack trace shows that you're using Cowboy. Provide the missing context, please.

Comment: Looks like you've provided your client side code, which looks absolutely unobjectional, but your error is apparently server side. If one was to guess based on the stack trace, one would have to wonder if you have exported a user_account_handler:handle_post/2 function?

Comment: Nathaniel, yes! I'm using cowboy to create a http server, this application will be a middleware that will be connected by http sending a JSON and conect to the server.